# The best choise for response image format with api?

Tags: java

I am writing an api to get list image in db, so i return it with type byte[]. and then it will be converted to base64 format. But I see pretty slow, so Should I keeping return that format or have any else ?

Comment: "But I see pretty slow" how much slow? How did you measure it and are you sure the encoding is the problem?

Comment: Why do you think it is necessary to convert it into Base64 in the first place?